# How to terminate child processes when a c# console application is aborted?

Tags: c#, process, wmi, console-application

I have a console application that spawns other win32 processes using WMI ManagementClass.I have a requirement when a user kills the console application through proc explorer or by pressing ctrl+c ,the application should terminate all the child processes it created.What is the best way to achive this?

Answer (score 3):

Keeping in mind that you have to take in your needs into account, you can do it like the sample below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace KillSpawnedProcesses
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<int> _processes = new List<int>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(Console_CancelKeyPress);

            StartProcesses();
            Console.Read(); //to hold up console
            Console.Read(); //to hold up console
        }

        static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            KillProcesses();
        }

        static void StartProcesses()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe";
                p.Start();
                _processes.Add(p.Id);
            }
        }

        static void KillProcesses()
        {
            foreach(var p in _processes)
            {
                Process tempProcess = Process.GetProcessById(p);
                tempProcess.Kill();
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sub-process has a message queue (Win32 message pumping), you can post WM_CLOSE to its main window, or define your own message. Otherwise, you can design your inter-process notification by using Sockets, Pipes, or Synchronization objects like Events.

The worst way is to kill the sub-processes.